# How to use position: fixed onScroll for Lottie Image, and then move to position: relative once scrolling complete

Tags: css, reactjs, web, animation, lottie

I am using a Lottie animation on my website, and I'm trying to recreate the flow here: https://neverland.agency/

When the user is scrolling through the lottie animation, it is position:fixed but once the scroll is done the position is relative.

Is it possible to change the position of the lottie animation once finished scroll, or should I be nesting it in a container which is relative? I've tried both so far, with neither working. My code snippet is below.

I'm using Lottie-Web for my animation.

```
import * as React from "react";
import "../styles/custom.css";
import lottie from "lottie-web";
import animationData from "../documents/CurveLightZoom.json";
import { getByDisplayValue } from "@testing-library/dom";

const LottieControl = () => {
  const lottieRef = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    var animDuration = 500;
    const anim = lottie.loadAnimation({
      container: lottieRef.current,
      renderer: "svg",
      loop: false,
      autoplay: false,
      // rendererSettings: {
      //   preserveAspectRatio: 'xMidYMid meet'
      // },

      animationData
    });


    // console.log(anim);

    function animatebodymovin(duration) {
      const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
      const maxFrames = anim.totalFrames;

      const frame = (maxFrames / 100) * (scrollPosition / (duration / 100));

     console.log("scroll", scrollPosition, anim.totalFrames - 1)

    //  anim.goToAndStop(frame, true);

      if (scrollPosition > 500) {
        anim.pause();
        // <div style={{ position: "relative",top: 0}} ref={lottieRef}></div>;
        
      
        
     }
     else {
      anim.goToAndStop(frame, true);
     }

    }

    const onScroll = () => {
      animatebodymovin(animDuration);
    };

    document.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

    return () => {
      anim.destroy();
      document.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
      };
  }, []);

  return <div 
  style=
  {
    
    { 
    position: "fixed",
    // top: 0,
    }
  } 
  ref={lottieRef}></div>;
};

export default LottieControl;
```